# How to persist retrofit or okhttp RequestBody and perform network call later

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

In case of no internet I want to like/create notices (also have file, multipart) or post comment locally and send to server as soon as network become available.

Url, method and headers can be persist easily but problem with persisting `Call.request().requestBody()`  to perform network call later

```
httpClient
            .build()
            .newCall(new Request.Builder()
            .headers(headers)
            .method(method,body)
            .build()
    ).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can be helpful to you, In my case I was storing all the requestbody (json request) in local db and then as soon as app is connected to network i send all the request to server in background on FIFO basis.

Comment: I need some generic solution (RequestBody has write method) for all cacheable requests. Also using with `firebase-jobdispatcher` to execute